# Bootstrap 5 nav pills not working properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5, cdn

guys. I'm working on a feature for a project where I need Bootstrap 5 nav pills to switch between column and grid view but they don't respond as they should (it shows the content on the first pill but nothing when the second one is clicked).

I tried with the different versions of Nav Tabs in the documentation page but none worked.

Answer (score 1):

### The solution I found:

After hours of research and experimenting, I decided watching a YouTube tutorial on Nav Pills and found out the problem was the CDN version I was using.

My code had the `4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js` version of the CDN while using the 5.3.0 documentation.

So changing it to the `5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js` CDN made it work.

P.S: I'm not sure if the difference between the `minified` and `budled` versions also make a relevant defference. Hope it helps you!